# Maintainability while adding custom findByX methods to DAOs

Tags: domain-driven-design, maintainability

I'm in the beginning of a project which I want to have the best testability and maintainability possible. To achieve this, I'm reading a lot about concepts in the DDD area, mainly.

To get you contextualized, suppose the following entities:

- **User**
  It's basically a container for Accounts (see below) and configurations;
- **Account**
  It's a way for a User to login. Each User may have various accounts, one for each OAuth provider (Facebook, Google, etc);
- **Session**
  It's a token that points to a User + expiration date. Each login generates a new Session.

I need to find a User by Account (when I'm logging in) or Session (when I'm already logged in).

However, I'm afraid that I'll be bloating my DAOs with `findByX` methods - these seem to be the most performant and simple to understand, but they kinda couple the DB structure to some business rule - or am I wrong?

[This post](http://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/) says that I should be using a `Specification` interface, which its implementations should return the right query criteria.

Is there any problem I may face upfront - like bloating my DAOs with `find` methods, or am I just over concerned with this architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findBy methods don't couple you to the database structure, they couple you to *business requirements*. Personally, I don't mind repositories that have multiple findBy methods, as long as they are clean and neat. For example:

```
User findById(string id);
User findByEmail(string email);
User findByUserName(string userName);
```

To me seems like a clean interface. It can get a little big in the long run, but I'm not too concerned about that because the methods are small and easy to read.

On the other hand, compare this:

```
IList<User> findByEmailLikeAndNameLike(string email, string name);
IList<User> findByEmailWithStatusAndLastLoginAfter(string email, UserStatus status, DateTime lastLogin);
IList<User> findByEmailAndStatus(string email, UserStatus status);
```

These are very specific methods that are still business requirements but get VERY unwieldy in the long run and duplicate a lot of logic. I'd replace those three methods by a generic findBy that I can pass a specification to.